# #->php -v и #->php -r "phpinfo();" | php возвращают разные версии PHP

Tags: php, centos, yii2, composer

Есть VPS от `reg.ru` под `centos6_php_selector` с модулем переключения PHP. 
Настроил для пользователя все как в [инструкции](https://www.reg.ru/support/hosting-i-servery/servery-vps/ispmanager/kak-smenit-versiyu-php-na-vps)
Устанавливаю например при помощи `composer` `yii2` он выдает ошибку что версия PHP ниже необходимой. Заливаю `yii2` из архива, смотрю `requirements.php` там версия PHP уже та что надо.

Comment: **Поправка:** #->php -v и #->php -r “phpinfo();” | php возвращают одинаковые версии, но если вызвать в браузере скрипт где прописан phpinfo(); версии получатся разные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В системе установлено одновременно несколько версий PHP, что является частой практикой для хостеров. Один из них вызывается при запуске в консоли `php` (чтобы узнать, какой именно, попробуйте набрать `which php`). Какой-то другой работает с веб-сервером.

Чтобы работать в консоли с тем же PHP, с которым работает веб-сервер, нужно просто узнать путь до его бинарника и подложить себе в `$PATH`. Путь можно спросить у саппорта хостинга.